# The size of the project affect the initial loading time in a React SPA?

Tags: html, reactjs, image, performance, load

My spa made in React loads images a bit slow. One guy told me that the size of the project (I use local images) can make the page load slower the first time (Even if I don't use all). Is that correct? The size of my app (build folder) is around 4mb. Thanks.

Faster initial loading time (images mostly).

Comment: Your question could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as code, citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your question is correct and are able to answer. You can find more information on how to write good questions in the help center.

Comment: The answer is yes. The browser have to load the entire bundle before starting